# Linux - How to search for words in files and print how many times they occur?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to search through a directory, ARCHIVE, which contains many sub directories, each which contain files. Each file has an email address in it. I want to list all of the email address', with the @blah.com truncated, then list the occurrences for each name.

I figured out how to find the emails and truncate the @ part, but I can't figure out how to count how many times each individual name occurs.

```
grep -R '^To: ' $ARCHIVE | cut -d@ -f1 | awk  '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
```

Also for some reason I can't get this to work in a script; whenever I call it it does nothing, but if I put it in the command line it works.

Comment: `uniq -c` will print a count of how many occurrences there are for each word.

Comment: squiguy, Thank you so much. Is there a way I can then show the total? If I add | wc -l, it will print the total but nothing else

Comment: Yes, mostly, its just now I need it to add the total number of occurrences.  If I add | wc -l, it will print the total but nothing else.

Comment: show the total of what in particular?

Comment: The absolute total of occurrences for all emails. So using wc -l will do that, but if I put that in my code, it will just print the total number and nothing else.

Comment: would you like to see the individual count too? is that why when you type `wc -l` it outputs the total and you miss the rest of the previous output?

Comment: Yes, I want it to have the individual count for  the occurrences of the email, then to list the total number of emails at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with our long comment conversation I would do this:

```
grep -R '^To: ' $ARCHIVE | cut -d@ -f1 | awk  '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c > ind.txt && wc -l ind.txt >> ind.txt
```

This will take the output of the `uniq` command, write it to a file and then gather a total and append it to the same file for you to see at the bottom.

Or as Geoff pointed out you could do `uniq -c file.txt | awk '{print}END{print NR}'`.

Comment: Instead of using a temp file, after `uniq -c` add `| awk '{print}END{print NR}'`. The awk script prints each input line and then prints the number of records (i.e. lines) after reading all the input.

Comment: @GeoffReedy Thanks for the suggestion.  I will throw it in my answer as an alternative.  I didn't know if he wanted a file he could refer to later.

Comment: @squiguy, thank you so much for helping me for so long. Have a good one!

Comment: I am still unable to put my code into a script and run it. For some reason it will only run if I enter it manually in the terminal.                                                                   I call it: "./prgm " it goes through but doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Alyx Do you make a shell script?  It would probably need the `.sh` extension and be invoked at the command line by `sh prgm.sh`.  It is also good practice to place this line at the top `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: I got it working, thanks. Just need to export ARCHIVE. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Grep has a count option.

If you device a reg-ex thats powerful enough to match an email directly you may count all the occurrences with one command:

E.G.

```
$ echo -e "1\n\2\n3\n\4" | grep [0-9] -c
4
```

That said, I think what you're doing is best done with sed and awk:

```
sed 's/@.*//' tmp/mails | sort | uniq   | \
while read name ;
do 
   echo $name; 
   awk '$1 ~ /'$name'/ { ++c; } END {print c;}' tmp/mails ;
done

cat tmp/mails:
$ cat tmp/mails 
arne@gmail.com
arnt@treemail.com
jonas@hotmail.com
arne@gmail.com
kari@yahoo.no
alex@wee.moo
arne@gmail.com
jonas@hotmail.com
kari@yahoo.no
jonas@hotmail.com
kari@yahoo.no
```

---

```
$  sed 's/@.*//' tmp/mails | sort | uniq   | while read name ;do echo $name; awk '$1 ~ /'$name'/ { ++c; } END {print c;}' tmp/mails ;done 
alex
1
arne
3
arnt
1
jonas
3
kari
3
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but squiguy's solution fitted my needs more. Have a good one.